# Missing table input task in kettle GUI

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm using Kettle 7.0. In the design view I'm unable to find table input task.

Does this require a plugin? Is it a paid for functionality?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a job which is different than transformation. Transformation have table input step and it is the place where you add all your ETL logic. It is free and comes with community edition. Check the attached image.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to create a job. The table input step is not available in jobs. 
Try creating a new transformation instead of a job - table input is listed under the "Input" drop down under the Design tab.